# Is it possible to compile Cinder on Visual Studio Express 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cinder

I'm interested in using Cinder, but version 0.8.4 only supports VS 2008 and VS 2010. Has anyone been able to get Cinder to work/compile on VS Express 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Visual Studio C++ 2012 (Express) has been added in the recently released version 0.8.5. 
See for more information: http://libcinder.org/blog/posts/7_cinder-085-released/